# Replace and transform text using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text with a pattern. And it needs to be transformed to a text that is more readable to the user.

```
//Rawtext => transformed text
@[John](john@gmail.com), how are you? => @John, how are you?
Good morning @[Doe](doe@gmail.com) => Good morning @Doe.
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Note: related to the react-mentions package for reactjs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

```js
const regex = /@\[([^\]]+)\]\([^\)]+\)/g;

console.log('@[John](john@gmail.com), how are you?'.replace(regex, '@$1'));
console.log('Good morning @[Doe](doe@gmail.com)'.replace(regex, '@$1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
const re = /\[(\w+)\]|\(.+\)/g

const a = '@[John](john@gmail.com), how are you?'
const b = 'Good morning @[Doe](doe@gmail.com)'

const result_A = a.replace(re, '$1')
const result_B = b.replace(re, '$1')

console.log(result_A)
console.log(result_B)
```